# Оптимизация запроса - формирование json

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Добрый вечер дорогие друзья. Есть вопрос. JOIN-ом объединил две таблицы

```
    'SELECT portfolio.id, portfolio.name, images.path from portfolio join images on portfolio.id = images.portfolio_id'
```

и получил такую вот выборку.

```
id => 1, name => first, path => cars1.jpg
id => 1, name => first, path => cars2.jpg
id => 2, name => second, path => cars3.jpg
id => 2, name => second, path => cars4.jpg
```

Теперь мне необходимо сформировать эту выборку в json следующего вида:

```js
[
0: {
    id: 1, 
    name: first, 
    path: [
        0: cars1.jpg, 
        1: cars2.jpg
        ]
    },
1: {
    id: 2, 
    name: second, 
    path: [
        0: cars3.jpg, 
        1: cars4.jpg
        ]
    }
]
```

У меня в принципе получилось это сделать, но правда идиотским способом:

```js
$result = [];

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from portfolio");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $query_images = mysqli_query($connection, "select path from images where portfolio_id ="."$id");

    while($image_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_images)) {
        $row['images'][] = $image_row['path'];
    }
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Потому ребятки очень сильно хочется услышать ваше мнение. Подмогните плиз. :)

Comment: Ходите по первой выборке и сверяйте текущий id.

Comment: Пример не приведете? Уже неделю голову ломаю :) Понимаю, что элементарно, но не доходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто пройтись по первой выборке:

```
$arr=[
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "first", "path" => "cars1.jpg"],
    ["id" => 1, "name" => "first", "path" => "cars2.jpg"],
    ["id" => 2, "name" => "second", "path" => "cars3.jpg"],
    ["id" => 2, "name" => "second", "path" => "cars4.jpg"],
];

foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $result[$v['id']]['id']=$v['id'];
    $result[$v['id']]['name']=$v['name'];
    $result[$v['id']]['path'][]=$v['path'];
}

$result=array_values($result); // сброс ключей (по желанию)

echo '<pre>'; print_r(json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

или сразу в while

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $result[$row['id']]['id']=$row['id'];
    $result[$row['id']]['name']=$row['name'];
    $result[$row['id']]['path'][]=$row['path'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. :) Очень признателен.